# Xcode, change background color of selection

Tags: macos, xcode

Like text editing apps, i would like to change background color of some selection in Xcode editor.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the `Font and Color Preferences`?

You can customize the appearance of source code and console text by changing their colors and fonts in Fonts & Colors preferences.

1. Choose Xcode > Preferences and click Fonts & Colors.
2. Click either Source Editor or Console near the top of the preferences window.
3. Select a theme in the left column.
4. Select a syntax category in the detail area.

---

Then if you want, you can also customize colors for the: background, selection, cursor of the source editor and the console.

Comment: yes, i did, it is not what i am looking for, thats for fixed background and colors, i want to highlight different parts of my code....

Comment: You can do that there. Just click on the keywords